# Running standalone Jar vs Web start

Tags: java, jar, javafx-2, jnlp

I have a JavaFX program which runs smoothly as a standalone Jar, but when I try to use java web start (i.e. run it using a JNLP file), the program tends to slow down after a while. Looking at the CPU usage through visualVM, it tends to gradually increase with time. Is there any parameters that need to be set when running a JNLP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I fixed the problem:

For debugging I had a lot of System.out.println(); in the code which would get triggered very frequently, somewhere along every 50ms. If running from a standalone jar, the CPU usage isn't that high, but through Java web start, the CPU usage was exceptionally high, I guess because of the sandbox mode overhead. Anyway, removing the prints significantly decreased CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

From references [here](http://uzzal.wordpress.com/2009/07/24/javafx-or-flash-which-to-choose/) and [here](http://www.loadui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=15972) seems that on the first startup JavaFX needs to load additional modules and also it may be some "wait to time out" delays related to the Oracle server migration. These modules, however, should normally be cached so it normally ought to start much faster second time. Also, both references deal with the very old version 1.3 - bugs that were present in this old version may be fixed long time ago.

This basically means that JavaFX more for is not well suitable for running some decoration that has no much value for the the user. Most of the people would wait for a serious application to load I think for somewhat the comparable time as they spend to download the standalone installer.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The problem though is that the slow down occurs after start up, running the program for a couple of minutes. So while looking at the CPU graph in the Task Manager, the CPU usage increases gradually every couple of minutes by a couple of percent when using the JNLP. This does not occur when running the bare jar file.

Comment: Rise of machines. Have you tried to update to the newest version?

Comment: The links in this answer refer to the obsolete JavaFX 1.3 version and some of the information in them is doubtless no longer relevant.  The authors basic conclusion may be correct, though it has little to do with the question.

Comment: May be relevant if he runs the obsolete version. Then the solution is to update.

Comment: Running the latest version of Java.

Comment: Some other bug may or not show up for the particular application but every application needs to start first. From the other side, there are no any references on the web that others would also experience this problem. Probably we deal with some specific issues in exactly your setup, and nothing can be said with the amount of information provided. Voting to close as too localized.